# specifying a recovery file in nvi

Tags: swap-file, nvi

I have an nvi session that got interrupted, and I'd like to recover my edits.

When I type `vi -r`, it tells me "no files to recover."  But there is a recovery file in `/var/tmp/vi.recover`, and when I run `strings` on that file, I can see that it contains text from the interrupted session.  So if I can point nvi to that recovery file, I should be able to recover my edits.

However, there appears to be no (documented) way to specify a recovery file.  The -r option does not take any parameters of its own; the only thing that can follow it is the name of the original file.  But since vi has apparently lost the association between the original file and the recovery file, `vi -r myfile` just tells me, "No files named myfile, readable by you, to recover".  How can I tell it to use a given recovery file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `nvi` uses a special "index file" in `/var/tmp/vi.recover/`, named `recover.XXXXX` (where `XXXXX` is randomly generated). On my system the contents look like:

```
X-vi-recover-file: /home/martin/recover
X-vi-recover-path: /var/tmp/vi.recover/vi.AI8Iqs
Reply-To: root
From: root (Nvi recovery program)
To: martin
Subject: Nvi saved the file recover
Precedence: bulk

On Mon Jun 22 17:30:01 2015, the user martin was editing a
file named /home/martin/recover on the machine
martin-xps.lico.nl, when it was saved for recovery. You can
recover most, if not all, of the changes to this file using
the -r option to nvi:

        nvi -r /home/martin/recover
```

By creating a new `/var/tmp/vi.recover/recover.XXXXXX` file with the above contents, and changing the first two "headers" (`X-vi-recover-file` and `X-vi-recover-path`) to the correct paths, you should be able tell `nvi` to pick up your recovery file.

... This seems to be the "easiest" way, as far as I can see ...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't believe the recover.XXXXX file is acting as an index; I actually have one of these files in /var/tmp/vi.recover/ (from a different editing session, one whose loss I don't care about) and its presence does not make `vi -r` display any results.  This file appears to just contain the text of the autogenerated email.  But I think this is the right track: *somewhere* nvi must store an index associating original files with recovery files, and adding the appropriate entry to this index would solve my problem.

Comment: Odd.  Despite `vi -r` not acknowledging the existing recover.XXXXX file, when I created a new phony one with the file I care about, nvi picked it up and recovered it without complaint.  Perfect!