# In nvi, how do I undo "already locked, session is read-only?"

Tags: tmux, nvi

On Mac OS Big Sur (11.6.3) with `nvi` 1.81.6 and several `tmux` panels, I accidentally quit Terminal.

Now opening files leads to the message

```
<file> already locked, session is read-only
<file> unmodified, readonly: line 1
```

After consulting [this answer about recovery files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3664/41179), I was a little confused about the files in /var/tmp/vi.recover/ directory.

The recover.XXXXX files appear to be plaintext emails starting with two special headers,

- `X-vi-recover-file` and
- `X-vi-recover-path`

The second header value points to a path like /var/tmp/vi.recover/vi.YYYYY, which can be *either* a file or directory.

When it is a file, it is binary. When it is a directory, it is empty.

After creating a copy of the recover.XXXXX file, and seeing it was pointing to "correct" paths already, it was not clear what to update the values to. Using `nvi -r <file>` just outputs

```
No files named <file>, readable by you, to recover.
```

Anyway, I removed all the recover.* files and vi.*/ folders, and `nvi` still opens the file read-only.

Is there a permanent solution, where I do not have to use `:set noro` each time I edit the file?

Comment: perhaps try `:set nolock`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank-you. After adding `set nolock` to the nvi startup file ~/.nexrc, the read-only issue is resolved. However, a nice "feature" of the read-only warning is knowing the file is opened already (in another tmux panel or new Terminal tab). The question originally did not mention this, so I'll update to provide more context.

Comment: Note that answers really belong below, in the answer section, and not in the Question. Another thing to try: find out if any processes are still using the file (_e.g._, via `lsof`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank-you for that. Running `lsof <file>` does show one entry, and it is for `nvi`. I have no visible editing sessions for the file; maybe this is running in the `tmux` session from before I quit Terminal? I can check for that. In the meantime, should I make the workarounds above separate Answers?

Comment: Separate answers is probably the best option, but you can also agglomerate them into a “Workarounds” answer if you want. You can use the [edit] button to update posts.

Comment: Separate answers added. I can mark the `tmux kill-session -a` post as the Answer in a bit, unless otherwise suggested. Thank-you again @D.BenKnoble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a lingering `tmux` session that has an `nvi` editing session locked to that file.

You can verify this with `lsof <file>` to determine which process still has a reference to the file.

In this case,

- `tmux ls` to list all windows
- `tmux kill-session -a` to exit all windows except current

After exiting all windows except the current one (which does not have the read-only file open), `nvi <file>` did *not* warn about read-only as desired.

Thanks to [@DBen.Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) for helping me down this trail.

Answer (score 0):

Disable read-only with `:set noro`.

Using `:w` will now let you save as normal, at least until the next time you edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is opened read-only, you can force overwrite the file each time with `:w!`

Be careful, as this may invalidate other instances of the file opened in other editing sessions. Saving in those sessions may overwrite previous changes in the window where you used `:w!`

Answer (score 0):

Add `set nolock` to the nvi startup file ~/.nexrc to *always* disable read-only warnings.

[Per comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36914/in-nvi-how-do-i-undo-already-locked-session-is-read-only#comment66227_36914) from [@D.BenKnoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me after suggestions above failed:

```
mv filename some-other-dir
cp some-other-dir/filename .
```